# Phrases used to replace" I think"

Tags: american-english, british-english, subcontinental-english, australian-english, contemporary-english

Can anybody  suggest phrases or sentences I can  use instead of "I think" when it comes to  giving opinions
Thank you.

Comment: Choose a relevant modal pragmatic marker from eg [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_modal_adverbs). 'It's my opinion that', 'In my opinion,', 'I'd have thought that', 'Probably,', 'Possibly,',  'Wouldn't you agree that' are some of the flavours available.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, would you be prepared to paste that as a full Answer?

Comment: Hello and welcome. This site is not a thesaurus. It also does not work well for questions that have any number of equally correct answers. And frankly, if you can't think of a dozen synonyms of "I think" yourself, then you must not be writing. You must be reading. Stop writing right now. You are not ready for it.

Comment: As The Dude in "The Big Lebowski" might say, "Yeah, well, you know, that's just, like, my opinion, man."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, I believe, I surmise, I suppose, it seems. However, if part of a long piece with many opinions, it's generally good writing policy to give a single indication or disclaimer somewhere early on, rather than continuously bombarding your readers with these phrases.